# Random generated number for percentage of likelyhood

Tags: c

My programming class is having us do dog race betting, and one of the aspects of it is putting the Odds of a dog (9 total) winning into a struct. For example, dog 1 is supposed to win 40% of the time, dog 2 is supposed to win 10% of the time, etc. Our teacher has also made one of our goals to "demonstrate the ability to generate and use random numbers." Here's what my struct/array is:

```
//DOG
typedef struct {
    char Name[100];
    int Payout;
    double OddsWin;
}Dog;

Dog racers[9];
```

Any tips/ ideas for how to tackle this? Other than how to do the random generation of numbers with the probabilities, I am also wondering how I would use that to determine if a dog won or lost. Would the probability of a certain number equal a win? like if I made 1 = to a win, would I have to code it so that it generates 1 about 40% of the time for dog 1 and so on?

Comment: I wrote an answer below that tries to address the problem in a general manner. Please note that this platform is not designated for doing homework, so I will not write out the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if I understand you correctly and trying to simplify your question, you want to find a way to choose randomly between an array of Dog's (`racers`), based on their `OddsWin` field, which holds the chance they have to win (in percent, e.g. 40%, 20%, 5.6%, etc.).

General tip - always try to solve a programming problem without coding, and then start coding.

So basically you are trying to make a choice between X, say 4, dogs. Say they have the following odds:

```
dog 1 - 40% to win
dog 2 - 20% to win
dog 3 - 7% to win
dog 4 - 33% to win
```

So I would take an array of 100 pieces, and fill it up with 40 times 1, 20 times 2, 7 times 3 and 33 times 4. Then, I would choose a random number, between 0 and 99 (array indices), and check the array at than index. If the array's value in that index is 1, than dog 1 won the race, and same for the other dogs.

Maybe there's a more efficient way, but I think that solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be

> -Choose a random num between the range(initially 100)

> -assign it to the dog

> -subtract the num from range
> (loop till 8 and give the rest to 9)

Implementation has many alternatives, the easiest would be giving out values and in a way rigging the system to generate the said probability of that dog say out of 100, run down counters and choose the dog if val>0. Here you can have another random 0-9 generator as well to automate the process.